# Looping a sound file in Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to get a sound to play once the view loads and repeat the music throughout the app even while switching from different views. It does play once the view is loaded and continues after switching to different views but I can't get it to loop. I am using  for the sounds. Any help to get me to loop would be awesome

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef    soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef)@"beat", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Comment: why don't you use the `AVAudioPlayer` class? here is the **[Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)** for it.

Comment: @holex: You should make that an answer.

Comment: I actually tried AVAudioPlayer first but it wouldn't play any sound when the app started. It would compile but no sound would come up when I start the App. So I went with AudioToolbox which worked so I figured I guess I'd just go with it.

Comment: Okay tried it again, and, apparently some stuff were missing from my code. I don't really know what but I'm just relieved it works now :D Now using, AVAudioPlayer for looping the sound :D @holex guess it should have been an answer

Comment: @user1677210, okay, I'll make an answer then and you are welcome. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use the `AVAudioPlayer` instead, the solution would be something like this (with using `ARC`).

---

you need to define a variable in you class...

```
@interface MyClass : AnyParentClass {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

// ...

@end
```

...and you can put the following code in any of your methods to start playing...

```
NSURL *urlForSoundFile = // ... whatever but it must be a valid URL for your sound file
NSError *error;

if (audioPlayer == nil) {
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlForSoundFile error:&error];
    if (audioPlayer) {
        [audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1]; // -1 for the forever looping
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [audioPlayer play];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}
```

...to stop the playing is very easy.

```
if (audioPlayer) [audioPlayer stop];
```

Comment: Can I put thise line "if (audioPlayer) [audioPlayer stop];" in a another viewcontroller so when that view comes up it will stop all sound that is playing?

Comment: if you pass the pointer of your `AVAudioPlayer` instance to the another `UIViewController`, then you will send any message to the instance successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving you code into your Application Delegate and use a repeating NSTimer to repeat your playing action.

Example code:

```
// appDelegate.h
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
     UInt32 soundID;
}

//appDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef    soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef)@"beat", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);


    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:lenghtOfSound target:self selector:@selector(tick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    return YES;
}

-(void)tick:(NSTimer *)timer
{
   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Comment: Not a bad suggestion - I just peeked at the function declaration assuming I would find a callback there.

Answer (score 0):

Register a callback using the AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion function, as the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound function description advises. The problem with the timer is you may not start it exactly when the previous sound has finished.

Comment: yes, this might be a wiser way to solve this problem =) thanks for sharing your information...

Comment: How do I implement AudioSerivesAddSystemSoundCompletion to my code? I'm not sure how to fill up the parameters. What do I put in AudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc inCompletionRoutine?

Comment: Before I go do this, did you see @holex suggestion in the Question comments - why not use AVAudioPlayer?