# Stopping sounds and looping them in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops

Ok so im pretty new to Xcode and am trying to make a simple app. i need my sound to keep looping and stop when i press the stop button. Please help and thanks in advance. here is my code so far.
as you can see the sound plays once then stops .

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize Images;

-(IBAction)start:(id)sender;{
 AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(PlaySoundID);

Images.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Light.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Light1.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Light2.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Light3.png"], nil];


Images.animationRepeatCount = 99999999;
Images.animationDuration = .2;
[Images startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:Images];

}

-(IBAction)stop:(id)sender;{

    [Images stopAnimating];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSURL *SoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Siren"   ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SoundURL, &PlaySoundID);


[super viewDidLoad];

Images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Light.png"];
[self.view addSubview:Images];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654019/looping-a-sound-file-in-cocoa-touch

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Siren" 
ofType:@"wav"]];


AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL
error:nil];
```

for "infinite" number of loops:

```
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
```